# Retrieve the content of access-permitted private google sheets from API?

Tags: python, google-sheets, permissions, google-sheets-api, permission-denied

I have an access to the not-mine private spreadsheet on the Google Sheet. When I access to that spreadsheet from browser, everything is fine. But, when I try to retrieve the content of that spreadsheet through Google Sheets API [using Python](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python), I am getting 403 error - "The caller does not have permission".

The problem is I can not ask the owner to give me one more permission for my API.

Can I retrieve the content of that spreadsheet somehow? Maybe using some tools?

Answer (score 0):

You prolly can access it because you got the link from someone. But to access it using the API will require you to be added in the permissions. Worth checking would be this [Google Drive SDK: Sharing Files](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2OIlwju8UM) tutorial video and the [Permissions docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions).